# simplepie: use my own thumbnail per feed in a multifeed page

Tags: image, feed, simplepie

I've been looking everywhere but haven't found the answer to the question: How can I use my own thumbnail per feed in a multifeed page? If I've overlooked the answer it would be due to the wrong search keys for which i apologize in advance.

I've got the following code so far (which is not much):

```
<?php
include_once('autoloader.php');
include_once('idn/idna_convert.class.php');

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'nld_nld');

$feed = new SimplePie();
$urls = (array(
    'http://myfeedurla.com' => 'descriptiona', 
    'http://myfeedurlb.com' => 'descriptionb',
    'http://myfeedurlc.com' => 'descriptionc'
    ));
$feed->set_feed_url(array_keys($urls)); // this should get parse only the URLS
$feed->set_cache_location('cache/');
$feed->init();

$feed->handle_content_type();
?>

// As from here I'm using the standard simplepie code to show multiple feeds and order them by day

      <?php

      // Set up some variables we'll use.
      $stored_date = '';
      $list_open = false;

      // Go through all of the items in the feed
      foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item) 
      {
        // What is the date of the current feed item?
        $item_date = $item->get_date('M jS');

        // Is the item's date the same as what is already stored?
        // - Yes? Don't display it again because we've already displayed it for this date.
        // - No? So we have something different.  We should display that.
        if ($stored_date != $item_date)
        {
            // If there was already a list open from a previous iteration of the loop, close it
            if ($list_open)
            {
                echo '</ol>' . "\r\n";
            }

            // Since they're different, let's replace the old stored date with the new one
            $stored_date = $item_date;

            // Display it on the page, and start a new list
            echo '<h1>' . $item->get_local_date('%A %d %B %Y') . '</h1><hr>' . "\r\n";
            echo '<ol>' . "\r\n";

            // Let the next loop know that a list is already open, so that it will know to close it.
            $list_open = true;
        }

        // Display the feed item however you want...
        echo '<li>' . $item->get_local_date('%H:%M') . ' | <h4><a href="' . $item->get_permalink() . '">' . $item->get_title() . '</a></h4></li>' . "\r\n";
      }
      ?>
```

Somewhere in the HTML I want to add the 'img scr=" . . "' etc. And there it should only refer to an image by the name 'descriptiona'.png respectively 'descriptionb'.png etc, per feed. Is this possible? And if yes, how?

If I should be more clear, pls don't hesitate to ask. Thanks in advance for the help!
Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so far I have one solution :) I use the title of the respective feeds in the img filename. I've added the following code:

```
<img src="images/' . $item->get_feed()->get_title() . '.png" width="12" height="12" />
```

Now I only hope that feeds won't use / or something in their titles... If someone has a better way of doing this, eg. by being able to add a personal title per feed, that would be very welcome.